# How to use this yahoo url : http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/me/guid

Tags: oauth, guid, yahoo

This should give me the guid of the current yahoo user logged in (me in this example) , but it doesn't work, here the manual page :

[YDN documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/introspective-guid-resource.html)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the OpenID protocol, and the library yahoo-yos to get the user ID (and his email) easily.